# Unable to show success/error message on same Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages

I have a VF Page that has a textbox and a button. On button click it should show success if there is a valid input in the textbox.

```
<apex:page controller="textInputsCon">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Enter quantity" >
  <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" >
  <apex:outputtext value="AC" styleClass="textual"/>
  <apex:inputText value="{!inputText1}"/>
  <apex:panelGrid> 
  <br/>
  <div align="center" draggable="false" >
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveList}" style="center-align"/>
  </div>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

**My Apex code is this :**

```
public with sharing class textInputsCon
{

     public String saveList { get; set; }
     public Integer inputText1{get;set;} 

     public PageReference saveList()
     {

       ProductStore__c obj;

       if(inputText1 !=null)
       ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM, 'Success!'));
       else
       ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Input value cannot be null.'));
       return null;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<apex:pagemessages>` tag right below the `<apex:form>` tag.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessage.htm

Comment: It is working thanks ... !!!!! but how to hide the rectangular box that comes up even before I am entering my data in the textbox ?